# Verify that f(z) = z(e^x) is analytical

Tags: derivatives, riemann-surfaces

iI have to show that the derivative of $f (z) = z (e ^ z)$ is $f '(z) = (e ^ z) + z (e ^ z)$

Then the solution would be something like:

$f(z) = (x+yi)[(e^x) \cos(y) + i(e^x) \sin(y)]$
$f(z) = x(e^x)\cos(y) + ix(e^x)\sin(y) + iy(e^x)\cos(y) - y(e^x)\sin(y)$

We organize

$f(z) = [x(e^x)\cos(y) - y(e^x)\sin(y)] + i [x(e^x)\sin(y) + y(e^x)cos(y)]$

We derive

$du/dx = (e^x)\cos(y) + x(e^x)\cos(y) - y(e^x)\sin(y)$
$dv/dy = (e^x)\cos(y) + x(e^x)\cos(y) - y(e^x)\sin(y)$

The first rule is met

$dv/dx = (e^x)\sin(y) + x(e^x)\sin(y) + y(e^x)\cos(y)$
$dv/dy = -(e^x)\sin(y) - x(e^x)\sin(y) - y(e^x)\cos(y)$

The second rule is met.

Now we have to check the answers

$f'(z) = du/dx + dv/dx$
$f'(z) = [(e^x)\cos(y) + x(e^x)\cos(y) - y(e^x)\sin(y)] + [(e^x)\sin(y) + x(e^x)\sin(y) + y(e^x)\cos(y)]$

$f'(z) = (e^x)[\cos(y) + x\cos(y) - y\sin(y)] + (e^x)[(\sin(y) + x \sin(y) + y \cos(y)]$

From this point I really do not know what I should do to demonstrate the derivative...

The answer I have to get is "$f'(z) = (e^z) + z(e^z)$"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please, use MathJax.https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Why not using the product rule?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative should be
$$
f'(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\color{red}{i}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
Thus
$$
f'(z)=e^x\cos y + xe^x\cos y - ye^x\sin y+
i(e^x\sin y + xe^x\sin y + ye^x\cos y)
$$
and so
$$
f'(z)=\underbrace{e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)}_{A(z)}+
\underbrace{e^x(x\cos y-y\sin y+i(x\sin y+y\cos y))}_{B(z)}
$$
The first summand is $A(z)=e^xe^{iy}=e^z$, the second is
$$
B(z)=e^x(x+iy)(\cos y+i\sin y)=ze^xe^{iy}=ze^z
$$
Just compute
$$
(x+iy)(\cos y+i\sin y)=x\cos y-y\sin y+i(x\sin y+y\cos y))
$$
Hence $f'(z)=A(z)+B(z)=e^z+ze^z$.

But this is wasting time. The product rule easily extends to analytic complex functions, with the same proof as in the real case.

Comment: I don't understand your procedure in the second step

How did I get to this? " ex(cosy+isiny)+ex(xcosy−ysiny+i(xsiny+ycosy)) ", Could you explain it step by step

Comment: @user426995 I added some details